# Creating table with 2 rows in pdf footer using itext

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, footer

Hi I want to add footer with 2 rows. 1st row will have document name with background color. 2nd row will have copy rights notes. I tried to create using ColumnText. but I am not able to set the background color for the row(only text getting background color). Is there any ay to achieve this. i spend my whole night to find a solution but not able to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have saved yourself a sleepless night by reading the documentation. You'd have discovered that you can set the background of a cell using the `setBackgroundColor()` method and that you can add a table at an absolute position using the `writeSelectedRows()` method.

Take a look at the [TableFooter](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/events/TableFooter) example:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.setTotalWidth(523);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("This is a test document"));
cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.ORANGE);
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("This is a copyright notice"));
cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
table.addCell(cell);
```

If you have more than one cell in a row, you need to set the background for all cells. Note that I'm defining a total width for the table (523 is the width of the page minus the margins). The total width is needed because we'll add the table using `writeSelectedRows()`:

```
footer.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 36, 64, writer.getDirectContent());
```

The resulting PDF looks like [this](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/table_footer.pdf). Make sure you define the margins of your page in such a way that the footer table doesn't overlap with the page content.