# Getting a Stack Overflow Exception generating a PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

As a continuation to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30276437/why-is-my-pdf-being-generated-as-blank) I have been trying out the header and footer functions for my PDF. After a little discussion I have changed quite a lot of code on the PdfPageEventHelper class. Below is what I have:

```
public class ReportHeaderFooter : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    public string HeaderTitle { get; set; }
    public IReportsAccessor ReportsAccessor { get; set; }
    private Image footerImg;
    private Image headerImg;
    private BaseColor headerColor;
    private PdfPTable tblHeader;
    public ReportHeaderFooter(IReportsAccessor reportsAccessor)
    {
        this.ReportsAccessor = reportsAccessor;
        var rootPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SaveFileRootPath"];
        headerColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ffffff")); // Not really but I don't want to give away the color

    }

    public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        base.OnOpenDocument(writer, document);
        // Set the initial header image...
        var headerImgInfo = ReportsAccessor.GetImage(4);
        headerImg = Image.GetInstance(headerImgInfo.ReportImage);

        // Set the initial footer image...
        var footerImgInfo = ReportsAccessor.GetImage(2);
        footerImg = Image.GetInstance(footerImgInfo.ReportImage);

        // Create the header table...
        tblHeader = new PdfPTable(2)
        {
            TotalWidth = document.Right,
        };
        tblHeader.SetWidths(new float[2] { document.Right - 70f, 70f });
        PdfPCell titleCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(HeaderTitle))
        {
            BackgroundColor = headerColor
        };
        tblHeader.AddCell(titleCell);
        PdfPCell imgCell = new PdfPCell(headerImg)
        {
            BackgroundColor = headerColor,
            HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT,
        };
        tblHeader.AddCell(imgCell);
    }

    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
        // Add the header table to the tops of the documents...
        document.Add(tblHeader);

        // Create the image at the footer.
        footerImg.SetAbsolutePosition(0, document.Bottom);
        document.Add(footerImg);            
    }
```

However, when I get to the document.Add(tblHeader) line on one of the pages (this is a reasonably large pdf (probably 10 pages)). I get a stack overflow exception).

What am I doing wrong here (if anything)? Last question that I asked I received a polite RTM, however, having read a lot of documentation, I can't see why something relatively simple would be causing a stack overflow. Please help me to understand.

Comment: Without running your code, my guess is that your `document.Add(tblHeader);` is causing a new page to be added which causes `OnEndPage` to be called which causes a new page to be added which causes `OnEndPage` to be called which causes a new page to be added which causes `OnEndPage` to be called which causes a new page to be added which causes `OnEndPage` to be called which causes a new page to be added which causes `OnEndPage` to be called which causes a new page to be added which causes `OnEndPage` to be called which causes a new page to be added which causes `OnEndPage` to be called...

Comment: With other words... whenever `OnEndPage` is called, the page already is full, at this time you cannot add content for automatic layouting on the page anymore. Thus, calling `document.Add` in that method can only fail. Look at the myriad examples using iText page events, especially those on stackoverflow or the iText web site.

Comment: So you're saying that a two cell table is likely too big for the page. I will have a look (if I remove the footer and run it what occurs) and report back here. I'm not really sure what the myriad of examples is going to do as I have already checked them.

Comment: The most important part of those examples is that they'll almost always add content at specific locations instead of relying on the abstraction layer to figure things out. I would look into wither `ColumnText` or `PdfPTable.WriteSelectedRows()`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the official documentation, it is **strictly forbidden** to add content to the `document` object in a page event. That `document` object **is not** the `Document` object you are using in your main code. Instead, it is an internal `PdfDocument` instance that is passed to the event for *read only* purposes.

If you want to add a table in a page event, you should use the `writeSelectedRows()` method. Please download the free ebook [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) and take a look at the chapter about events.

You'll find references to the following questions:

- ["'System.StackOverflowException" in "OnEndPage" event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285547/system-stackoverflowexception-in-onendpage-event-handler) (which what you are asking; reading the book would have helped you)
- [Creating table with 2 rows in pdf footer using itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122340/creating-table-with-2-rows-in-pdf-footer-using-itext)
- [How to add a table as a header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612105/how-to-set-a-100-header-in-itext-itextsharp-pdf)

Reading the documentation that is available for free can save you (and us) plenty of time ;-)

Comment: *As mentioned in the official documentation, it is strictly forbidden to add content to the document object in a page event.* - you should start throwing exceptions there.